# Class instances communication in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, instance

I am making a game that has several classes and each one do some kind of specific task.

I am completely new to OOP and I was wondering what I should do to make my class instances communicate between each other without recurring to static classes, methods and properties, which seems like an awful thing to do.

I am self-taught programmer, and I realize I do a lot of bad practices. So far I managed to make this work making both classes static but I wanted to know what I should do to make my code as good as possible.

Also, it would be nice if you could recommend me some resources/books/articles so I can read more about this topic (communcation between instances).

Here is some piece of code so you understand what I am talking about.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 instance1 = new Class1();
        Class2 instance2 = new Class2();

        // infinite loop
        while (true)
        {
            instance1.UpdateMethod(someValue);
            instance2.UpdateMethod();
        }
    }
}

class Class1
{
    int Property;
    UpdateMethod(int argument)
    {
        Property += argument;
        if(Property == 3000)
        {
            // I should change the state of instance2
        }
    }
}

class Class2
{
    UpdateMethod()
    {
        if(Time.GetTime() == SomeTime)
        {
            // here I want to change the state of instance1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's s small number of objects, such as in the example, couldn't you simply pass one instance to the other's update method as a parameter?

Comment: If I pass an instance to a method, and if I modify that instance, the instance in main() changes too?

Comment: In the example you've given, yes. Classes, being reference data types, will be changed. If you're using structs, the outcome will be different.

Comment: @Fer when you pass a reference type object, you aren't actually passing the instance; you're passing a reference to the instance. The caller's reference and the callee's reference denote the *same* instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an overview of common design patterns, I recommend

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Software_design_patterns

If there is a natural relationship between `Class1` and `Class2`, it's quite common for an instance of one to hold a reference to an instance of another.  For example, if you have a `Player` class, and the player has a `Weapon`, define your class like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

Specifically in your case, it looks like you want to update an instance of `Class1` from an instance of `Class2`.  I would suggest that you define a property on `Class2` that holds the related instance of `Class1`, just as in the example above.

This is called the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

> In software engineering, the composite pattern is a partitioning
>   design pattern. The composite pattern describes that a group of
>   objects are to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an
>   object. The intent of a composite is to "compose" objects into tree
>   structures to represent part-whole hierarchies. Implementing the
>   composite pattern lets clients treat individual objects and
>   compositions uniformly.

Another pattern frequently used to act on an object instance is the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

> In object-oriented programming, the command pattern is a design
>   pattern in which an object is used to represent and encapsulate all
>   the information needed to call a method at a later time. This
>   information includes the method name, the object that owns the method
>   and values for the method parameters. Three terms always associated
>   with the command pattern are client, invoker and receiver. The client
>   instantiates the command object and provides the information required
>   to call the method at a later time. The invoker decides when the
>   method should be called. The receiver is an instance of the class that
>   contains the method's code. Using command objects makes it easier to
>   construct general components that need to delegate, sequence or
>   execute method calls at a time of their choosing without the need to
>   know the owner of the method or the method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you two links and the content their is free to read

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx

A bit more on patterns with better details is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep

and final one from uncle bob good explanation on OOD Principles http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the state of an object from another class, you need a reference to it.  Common ways to do this are through the constructor:

```
public class Class2
{
    private readonly Class1 instance;

    public Class2(Class1 instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void UpdateMethod()
    {
        if(VisualStyleElement.TaskbarClock.Time.GetTime() == SomeTime)
        {
            // here I want to change the state of instance1
            this.instance.SomeProperty = "Some Value";
        }
    }
}
```

or through a parameter passed into the method

```
public class Class2
{
    public void UpdateMethod(Class1 instance)
    {
        if (VisualStyleElement.TaskbarClock.Time.GetTime() == SomeTime)
        {
            // here I want to change the state of instance1
            instance.SomeProperty = "Some Value";
        }
    }
}
```

In the first case you would call it like this:

```
Class2 instance2 = new Class2(instance1);
instance2.UpdateMethod();
```

And in the second case you would call it like this:

```
Class2 instance2 = new Class2();
instance2.UpdateMethod(instance1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be most welcome to the world of OOP!
One important thing to understand is the notion of **inheritance**. Inheritance regards to what **is**. A Child is a Person, and a Mother is a person.

Please, take a look at this model:

```
public class Person
    {
        protected string Name;

        public string WhatsYourName()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }

    public class Mother: Person
    {
        public Mother(string personName)
        {
            this.Name = personName;
        }
    }

    public class Child : Person
    {
        public Mother MyMother { get; set; }

        public Child(string personName)
        {
            this.Name = personName;
        }

        public string WhoAreYou()
        {
            return string.Format("My name is {0} and my mom is {1}", this.Name, this.MyMother.WhatsYourName());
        }
    }
```

Now, how do objects talk to each others? There are plenty of ways to achieve this, but it all comes to a simple concept: **references**.
When you create an object (x = new ...) you are creating a new **instance**, and you have its **reference**.

Now, look at this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mother mary = new Mother("Mary");
    Child bobby = new Child("Bobby");

    bobby.MyMother = mary;

    Console.WriteLine(bobby.WhoAreYou());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

See when we are setting Bobby's mother? We are passing its **object reference**.

Please, take a look at this code, I believe it can help.

Further on, I'd strongly recommend you to read about **design patterns**.
Maybe starting here: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what `Class1` and `Class2` are and if they need to be coupled or not.
If they do unrelated things and do not need to know about each other, you can use events to communicate changes between them:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 instance1 = new Class1();
        Class2 instance2 = new Class2();

        instance1.CriticalValueReached += instance2.DoSomething;
        instance2.TimeoutElapsed += instance1.DoSomething;

        // infinite loop
        while (true)
        {
            instance1.UpdateMethod(someValue);
            instance2.UpdateMethod();
        }
    }
}

class Class1
{
    int Property;

    public event Action CriticalValueReached;

    public UpdateMethod(int argument)
    {
        Property += argument;
        if (Property == 3000)
            RaiseCriticalValueReached();
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Whatever...
    }

    private void RaiseCriticalValueReached()
    {
        var handler = CriticalValueReached;
        if (handler != null)
            handler();
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public event Action TimeoutElapsed;

    public UpdateMethod()
    {
        if (Time.GetTime() == SomeTime)
            RaiseTimeoutElapsed();
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private void RaiseTimeoutElapsed()
    {
        var handler = TimeoutElapsed;
        if (handler != null)
            handler();
    }
}
```